# Python, type byte

Tags: python, types

I start with Python but I am really C/C++ based so thinking for me is little bit different. I am working with embeded stuff and I need to work with bytes. For example I have in my C code my typedefs for: u8, s8 (unsigned char, signed char) and similar u16, s16. But how can I use this idea with Python. For example I need to get sum of items `0xF0 + 0xAA` and I want to get `0x9A` not `0x19A` is exist some module for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps you can use ctypes.

```
>>> import ctypes
>>> _ = lambda i: int(ctypes.c_uint32(i).value)
>>> hex(_(0xF0 + 0xAA))
'0x19a'
```

Comment: I think this way is the best solution for me: 
u8 = lambda i: int(ctypes.c_uint8(i).value)
s8 = lambda i: int(ctypes.c_int8(i).value)

Answer (score 5):

I dont think, there is a straight forward way to do this. If you want 8 bit arithmetic, just `&` with 255

```
print hex((0xF0 + 0xAA) & 255)
```

**Output**

```
0x9A
```

**Note:** As chepner mentioned in the comments, `hex` is needed just to represent the result in hexadecimal. It has nothing to do with the arithmetic.

Comment: Note that `hex` is only necessary to print the output in hexadecimal format; it does not affect the arithmetic.

Comment: @chepner Added that as a note in the answer :)

Comment: I know that it not depend on hex format, Binary format... but what I need is some type with just 1byte size. So If there is a overflow it is not a runtime error. Just like C.

Comment: @Lodhart Native python doesn't come with any such datatypes, as with integers it supports arbitrary precision arithmetic.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [NumPy](http://www.numpy.org/) for this:

```
>>> import numpy
>>> a = numpy.array(range(200, 210), dtype=numpy.uint8)
>>> a
array([200, 201, 202, 203, 204, 205, 206, 207, 208, 209], dtype=uint8)
>>> a + a
array([144, 146, 148, 150, 152, 154, 156, 158, 160, 162], dtype=uint8)
```